# How to Run Rails on Shared Server Using Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, shared-hosting

I have a website http://example.com and would like to to host a Ruby on Rails generated app from http://example.com/projects/ruby.

I am using Heroku with the Zerigo DNS addon (or open to OpenShift if that works).

I tried installing nDeploy through my CPanel but [Siteground][1] (my web host) does not seem to allow access to Apache or a command line(?).

My goal is to present my project through my website (not through a Cloud9 or Heroku domain). Can someone please point me, in the right direction.

On Heroku when I try to press "Add Domain" from the Control Panel I receive a message:

*"can't have more than 1 domains / check *** for a larger plan that accommodates your needs"*

Comment: You would be able to install nDeploy on a VPS. nowadays they come from as low as 10 usd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `Heroku` to host your rails app (which uses Amazon E3), you'll not be hosting it on your shared hosting *at all*.

Your fix will come from [the following](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains):

[image]

All you're doing with Heroku custom domains (which you need a pro account for), will be forwarding traffic from your `domain.com/path` to your `heroku` app.

Now, I don't know about how Heroku would deal with being routed to - from a subfolder - but I know for a fact that the only thing which will help you here is are the **DNS setup** for your domain.

In that section, you need to be able to add / change the `CNAME` reference as above.

Heroku explains it best:

> Configuring your DNS provider for a root domain is similar to configuring a DNS provider for a subdomain. However, whereas with subdomains the type of record to configure is always a CNAME, with root domains the type of record depends on the DNS provider

I can be more specific if required